# Batch findstr return only field value

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

How can I return only the value field from a command in batch? For example:

```
ipconfig /all | findstr "Host Name"
```

Will return

```
Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : YOUR_HOSTNAME
```

But I only want the value. In this case, YOUR_HOSTNAME.

Also, if there are more than one line, it should get the first match from the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %b in ( 'ipconfig /all ^| findstr /c:"Host Name"') do set "hostname=%c"
set "hostname=%hostname:~1%"
```

from the prompt. Change `%b` and `%c` to `%%b` and `%%c` to use within a batch file.

The caret escapes the pipe, telling `cmd` that the pipe is part of the command to be executed, not of the `for`.

The `/c:"Host Name"` makes `findstr` find the precise string `Host Name`. As you have it, `findstr` would find *either* `Host` *or* `Name`, which would deliver a hit on

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
```

for instance.

To force the first match, append `&goto label` to the `for` command line and insert `:label` between the two lines in a batch file.

Comment: But what does ^ do in ^| ? Its kinda hard to look up, since google dont let me search with symbols.

Comment: @ItsMeBrille :The caret escapes the pipe, telling cmd that the pipe is part of the command to be executed, not of the for

Comment: maybe a simple `echo %computername%` would be easier?

Comment: @Gerhard :possibly. Equally, `hostname` will probably work as a command, but the method I've shown can be applied to other strings from `ipconfig` or other commands. Not that it's particularly original, of course...

Answer (score 2):

If you want the hostname, Windows already provides a program to give exactly that without any string parsing.

```
"%__APPDIR__%HOSTNAME.EXE"
```

Use it in a `batch-file` to set a variable.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('"%__APPDIR__%HOSTNAME.EXE"') DO (SET "THISHOST=%%~A")
ECHO THISHOST IS %THISHOST%
```

If you want to step up to .Net or PowerShell, there is:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
```

Comment: As `%__APPDIR__%` already expands to a path with a trailing separator, there is no need to include another, i.e. `@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%__APPDIR__%HOSTNAME.EXE') Do @Set "THISHOST=%%G"`

Comment: @Compo, I agree that the additional REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash) is not needed. Can you agree that it is benign? To me, it is more easily and quickly recognized as a path when the REVERSE SOLIDUS is used.

Comment: It's benign @lit. However, the reason why I'd prefer it gone, other than just pure correctness, is that many languages have a need to escape backward slashes with another, and doubling it here could therefore add unnecessary confusion too.

Answer (score 1):

Then, you would not believe this, but there is an environment variable called `%computername%`

Try it yourself:

```
echo %computername%
```

Comment: This is true. However, the COMPUTERNAME variable can be manipulated by the user or a program (malicious or not). The output of HOSTNAME.EXE is not affected by the value of COMPUTERNAME.